# Azure application service is missing .css file content

Tags: css, yaml, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, blazor-server-side

I finally have my Blazor .Net 6 application working as an Azure app service.  One last problem I can't figure out, I'm missing css from my project's wwwroot folder. But the font-icons are all there.

[image]

when I load the site no css has been applied and there is nothing in the Style Editor window

[image]

I'm using Azure DevOps pipeline to deploy the code and I'm fairly certain that's where the problem lies but I haven't found much on SO or general Google searches looking for "Azure app service missing css".  Here is my .yaml file

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: nuget.config

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)" /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true  /p:OutDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'  

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/deploy.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
    
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
    
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: '<sub name>(2442165c-339d-4e83-a443-*******)'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    WebAppName: 'hrchangemanagement'
    deployToSlotOrASE: false
    ResourceGroupName: 'HRChangeManagement'
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/deploy.zip'
    RuntimeStack: 'DOTNETCORE|6.0'
    StartupCommand: 'dotnet "HR Taxonomy Change Management.dll"'
```

Any suggestions you have are welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building Web App, the **`wwwroot`** folder will not be automatically copied to the output directory (**OutDir**) of the build by default. Same behavior when building both in Azure Pipelines and on local machines.

To let the **`wwwroot`** folder can be automatically copied to the output directory when building the Web App. You can add below command to the Post-build event of your project file (for example, **`MyWebApp.csproj`**).

```
xcopy .\wwwroot $(OutDir)\wwwroot /s /i
```

- The **`.\wwwroot`** is the relative path of **`wwwroot`** folder in the project. Replace it with the actual relative path in your project if it is different than this one.
- The **`$(OutDir)\wwwroot`** is the target path that the **`wwwroot`** folder will be copied to. You also can change it to a different path based on your actual requirements.

See below example as reference:

- **Settings on the project.**

  [image]

  [image]
- **Result.**

  [image]

Comment: I run the build on Azure with your changes and the bootstrap css is applied but the site.css is not.  I can see the file in Inspector now but its not being applied.  In the home/site/wwwroot folder, I now have another wwwroot folder with the css files.  Site.css is there but I don't think the application is finding it.  I tried removing wwwroot from the output location of the script to put the CSS folder under the first wwwroot, but then none of the css worked.  I'm hoping there is a small tweak to your script that might fix this?  BTW, I added a switch "/y" to your script to overwrite files.

Comment: I should have asked, is this a tweak with the script or a completely separate problem.  Thanks!

Comment: I found a 404 error for the site.css (strict-origin-when-cross-origin) which is why my css isn't loading.  unrelated.